# How to Skip a Transformation in Pentaho Data Intigration job

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have single Job to run multiple Transformations.  I want to parameterize this single job by some parameter that decides if all the transformation has to run or a single transformation has to run based on the name passed.

E.g

Start -->  PARAMETER( Transformation_NAME OR ANY_IDENTIFIER that will decide to run all the transformation )

if (Parameter = Transformation_Name)
run only that particular transformation 
else if (Parameter = ANY_IDENTIFIER )
run all the transformations as part of that main job

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to right-click on the hops (arrows) and enable/disable them. But I think you are looking for something more elaborate. In that case the `Simple Evaluation` step method described below is a very good solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Set Environment Variable:** 
             jobName or youCanUseTransformationName - as we are going to pass the transformation name as a value in this environment variable

[image]

**Step 2: Transomrmation Setup in main job:** Set all the transformation in parallel mode with Precomponent as Simple Evaluation as shown.

[image] below.

**Step 3: Configure Simple Evaluation component :** Double click on the simple Evaluation component.

Set

Evaluate: Variable

Variable Name : Enviroment Variable Name

Type : String

Sucess Condition : if value in List

Value :  TransformationName,Unqique_Identifier value (here i have passed as zero)

NOTE: Repeat Step 3 for all the Simple Evaluation Component with value as respective Transformation name, Unique Identifire

in our case,

if set jobName = Transformation Name,

Then it will run only that particular transformation for which Transformation Name is passed in Environment Variable

if passed 0

then all the transformation will execute in one go

[image]